# Eclipse Remote Application Platform (RAP) - Deploy Custom Theme

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rap

Currently trying to get my Eclipse RAP application to work with a custom styling. The documentation is giving me one headache after another and it's really hard getting into it.

Following their docs and trying to extend the default theme, I have set up my plugin.xml as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>
   <extension
     point="org.eclipse.rap.ui.entrypoint">
      <entrypoint
            applicationId="org.______.rap.branding.application"
            id="org.______.rap.branding.entrypoint"
            brandingId="______"
            path="/rap">
      </entrypoint>
   </extension>
   <extension
         id="org.______.rap.branding.application"
         point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.applications">
      <application
            cardinality="singleton-global"
            thread="main"
            visible="true">
         <run
               class="org.______.rap.branding.Application">
         </run>
      </application>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.perspectives">
      <perspective
            class="org.______.rap.branding.Perspective"
            id="org.______.rap.branding.perspective"
            name="name">
      </perspective>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.rap.ui.branding">
      <branding
            id="______"
            themeId="org.eclipse.rap.rwt.theme"
            title="______ Theme">
      </branding>
   </extension>
   <extension
    point="org.eclipse.rap.ui.themes">
      <themeContribution
         file="theme/______.css"
         themeId="org.eclipse.rap.rwt.theme" />
    </extension>
</plugin>
```

I've blanked out some parts, just asume they're all the same keyword, lowercase letters only.

My .css-File is as simple as it could be to see, if the hook works:

```
* {
    background: red !Important;
}
```

But it just loads the default theme, no changes whatsoever and I can't detect the injection anywhere on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Appears the hook itself is correct, but RAP couldn't handle the *background*-property. Changing it to *background-color* instead did the trick.